# Codeigniter web page caching

Tags: php, codeigniter, caching, md5

How can i cache a particular part of the web page, I know how CI caching mechanism works also i am aware of Partial Caching.

Assume that we have a page with some dynamic data associated with. If i used caching then i cannot get the actual data on page refresh.

How can i override this problem ?

I have one idea in my mind, While inserting the data just keep another field, lets say `MD5_CONTENTS` which will store the MD5 hash of the contents ( Normally form fields ). And next time on update i can compare the MD5 strings to determine changes. If changes are found then delete the cache file.

I dont know this is gonna work or not, But its littlebit hard for my current implementation.

What is the best method to achieve Partial Caching ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Would the caching driver do the trick?

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/caching.html

```
$this->load->driver('cache', array('adapter' => 'apc', 'backup' => 'file'));

if ( ! $foo = $this->cache->get('foo'))
{
     echo 'Saving to the cache!<br />';
     $foo = 'foobarbaz!';

     // Save into the cache for 5 minutes
     $this->cache->save('foo', $foo, 300);
}

echo $foo;
```